# Problems with view containing data from an entity reference on the current user user profile

Tags: views, entities, users

Say I have a content type of Fruit, and I have nodes of this content type with titles "Apple", "Pear", "Banana". Then on a user profile I have a field of type Entity Reference (unlimited values) to nodes of type Fruit, so an individual user might have an entity references to "Apple" and "Banana" in this field.

I want to create a View which is a table, with each row being a fruit, and then an indication in the row (a tick or yes or whatever) if the current user has an Entity Reference to that fruit on their user profile.

I have created a Relationship (Entity Reference: Referencing entity) in the view to the Entity Reference on the User record. However, if I then add a "User referencing Content from field_fruit" field to my table, it returns a list, i.e. "Apple, Banana" on the Apple row and the same on the Banana row. This wouldn't be a problem except if there is no result it doesn't return an empty result, rather an empty list of nothings, i.e. ", , ," - which doesn't count as an empty result.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: create of users then add entity relation on it after that adds fields in view

Comment: Adi, sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Isn't that what I said I did in my third paragraph above?

Comment: have you ticked require this relationship? coz it seems you ticked. uncheck the checkbox

Comment: it is inverse of your current view when you create using user empty space will solved

Comment: Shabir - no I don't have that ticked.

Comment: Adi - you mean I should create a view of users and then display the table of rows of fruit? Interesting approach, but I'm not sure it will work because I want to display all the fruit, even if the current user doesn't have that entity relationship. I just want to mark those fruit (rows) that the user has on their user profile.